# NullReferenceException when adding value to session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to store a collection of strings in session, and I have a web method that I'm calling through a jQuery ajax call:

```
[WebMethod]
public string AddIdToSession(string userId)
{
    List<string> userIds = new List<string>();

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null && 
        HttpContext.Current.Session["userIds"] != null)
    {
        userIds = (List<string>)Session["userIds"];
        userIds.Add(userId);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["userIds"] = userIds;
    }
    else
    {
        userIds.Add(userId);
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("userIds", userIds);  // error here
    }

    return userId;
}
```

I'm getting an error when I try to add the id to session:

> **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable session access using the [**`EnableSession`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vbtskusingwebmethodattributeenablesession) property:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

Note that your `else` logic will fire in the case `HttpContext.Current.Session == null`, which is likely the cause of the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `[WebMethod]` to `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`  in order to access the current session.

Then you can access the current session like so:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable session for the web method, change the attribute to

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```